# Need for reverse evaluation?

Tags: appraisal

Usually, a project manager evaluates his team members.

But, shouldn’t there be an evaluation of the project manager by his team members?

Most of the companies are lacking this reverse evaluation, which to me, is the root cause behind employees frequently switching their jobs to find peace of mind.

Usually, an employee doesn’t quit his company; but he quits his boss.

Is there a good way for end-employees to let their company know that they need an evaluation of their project manager, because employees are afraid of being fired if they raise their voice?

Comment: If employees fear being fired for raising their voice, a reverse evaluation isn't going to help. Reverse evaluation only makes sense (and is often easily implemented) in a situation where both team and project manager trust each other already.

Comment: VTC opinion-based. This seems more like you're trying to start a discussion than find an answer to a question.

Comment: @Lilienthal The OP is asking for a way to give feedback without the fear of repercussions IMHO.

Comment: @MisterPositive Could be, but in that case this needs a really drastic edit.

Comment: I have edited out the capitals that you gave most nouns.

Comment: There are companies that do "360-degree reviews" or otherwise do what you are suggesting, so I don't see anything that needs discussion here. Either yours does or doesn't.

Comment: @Ahsan are you in Germany?

Comment: The company I work for allows anyone to give inputs to anyone's evaluation. The only person who can read that input is the person doing the review. If you want to criticize the trick is to either state things in such a way as the person won't be able to identify who said it or to "damn with faint praise" where you are effusive about the people who are good and very noncommittal about the people who are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only safe and effective way I have seen work is to offer anonymous feedback through a survey.

Many HR systems will allow the company to set up an anonymous survey allowing employees to freely vent on issues that impact their productivity and well being.

This may not have an immediate impact on you, because in these cases due to the fact that many folks won't take the survey, will provide only positive feedback, or provide such negative feedback the information becomes useless, HR will have to invest significant time to find the nuggets of good information to act on.

Your best bet though is to **suggest an anonymous survey**, and be sure that if the situation requires, that other team members speak out too.

Comment: The difficulty with "anonymous" surveys is getting those answering to trust that they are truly anonymous.

Comment: @alroc That is true

Comment: Thank You all for your Feedback.

Anonymous Survey will best work for me.